# navigation & tab bars black for a split second right after launch

Tags: ios

When launching or bringing my app from the background the navigation bar & tab bar are black for a split second before assuming storyboard defaults.
I feel there is somewhere a property enforcing this but I can't seem to find it.
Found something in the project properties info tab under "Custom iOS Target Properties"
where NavigationBar.Style = Default and NavigationBar.Translucent = NO which seem fine and don't affect the result.
It started happening around the iOS8 upgrade but can't time it very precisely.
Anyone has a clue on what might be causing this? Or where we set

Answer (score 0):

Your view controllers of tab bar should be subclassed with UIViewController not UITabBarViewController. Please check your header file